# Send Email on HTML

Tags: html, html-email, forms

I am making a website completely from scratch and I am facing a problem when I want to receive an email when the client presses the submit button. Here is my code on the form tag.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="MAILTO:myemail@hotmail.com?    subject=subject&message=message">
  <p class="contact1"><label for="name">Name</label></p>
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text">

  <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p>
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@hotmail.com" required="" tabindex="2" type="text">

  <p class="contact"><label for="Subject">Subject</label></p>
  <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" tabindex="2" type="text">

  <p class="contact"><label for="comment">Your Message</label></p>
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="4"></textarea> <br>
  <input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Send Message" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `mailto:` is meant for links `<a>`, not forms.

Comment: how am i fixing this ? can i include the <a> tag in the last input tag that i have my submit button somehow ? because i have tried several ways and could not figure that out.

Comment: You can't. You'll have to use server side protocols like PHP.

Comment: php it is then. i will start doing that. thanks for the help

Comment: I told you at the beginning it won't always work and I use PHP for such tasks

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

It is **impossible** to send emails with HTML, JavaScript, CSS or any client side language. You have to go server side. The most common choice for emails is PHP. So your opening form tag should look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
```

And then the code in mailer.php would be:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
mail("your_email@site.com", "Subject", "Message from your site. \n Name: ".$name." \n Message: ".$message);
```

Bear in mind that this is a very basic email script and does **not** protect against script injection and XSS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull this off you would need some level scripting (server-side I think... not sure if client side can do this...) to hold your values in a placeholder variable, and then repaint the screen with the and then inject them into the `<a>` tag.

If you want to simply pre-populate a standard link with a SUbject line, even body text, and use the individuals default mail client, you can dress up the link as such:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=This is an example SL
&body=Your body copy can go here \n ... and new lines can be made like that.
&cc=justincaseyouwantit@yoursite.com&bcc=final-protection@yoursite.com">
Click here to send an email</a>
```

if you wanted to use a form to build those links you would have to capture the form's input as variables, and then build the link with those variables defined, and then echo it to the screen.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/76cxQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it totally wrong.

When the user would press submit button. The form would be redirected to the new page, with the link that is provided in the `action` attribute.

Remember, most of the users have some default Email Clients installed on their System. I have Google Mail set as Default, some folk out there might have Outlook, some of us would love to use Thunderbird (by Mozilla).

These programs would have their own Algorithm to send emails. So the code that you're using would never succeed. If does, then it would send you an email as

Sender: client_email
Subject: Subject
Body:

No data in the body tag, since you're not including that method at all.

The above would be the email recieved to you. Also, if you do so, the Form Data would be **lost** and the software would try to ask the user for data as a new cycle.

I think you need to do something like the following.

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="send_email.html"> 
    <p class="contact1"><label for="name">Name</label></p> 
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text">     

    <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@hotmail.com" required="" tabindex="2" type="text">       

    <p class="contact"><label for="Subject">Subject</label></p> 
    <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" tabindex="2" type="text">   

    <p class="contact"><label for="comment">Your Message</label></p> 
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="4"></textarea> <br>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Send Message" type="submit">
</form>
```

And then, handle the Email sending request on the Server-side, and send it yourself using the Server-side Language you're using.

In that way, you'll also get the email, and the content that User wrote and tried to send you.

Comment: I understand what you are saying except the last 2 sentences. What do you mean handle the Email sending request on the Server-side and send it yourself using the Server-side Language you're using ? The only languages i used for my website are html5,css3,javascript and some jquery i copied. I havent used any php yet. I can use php just for the contact form cant i ?

Comment: When you're using the PHP for Contact form, you can use that for the Sending Email process too :) Can't you? I think you can. It would be just a few lines and it would be better in User Interface too. :) TO handle the rquests on your own and not letting a Third Party use the Information to send the email...:)

Answer (score -2):

I have to say: I am not a hundred percent sure.
But it is not possible to send E-Mails via HTML.
You need some kind of Server. Maybe try the Google AppEngine it is free(until some limit), easy to lern and has an extra E-Mail API.

Comment: This type of "answer" would work better as a comment. I can see you're new here--you might want to have a look at the FAQs to get a better sense of expectations.

Answer (score -2):

It may not always work. Look at http://webdesign.about.com/cs/forms/a/aamailtobroke.htm

Personally I never used such solution. I use always PHP to send email

When I use your solution my e-mail client opens correctly but mail content doesn't look nice.

But when I use:

```
<form action="mailto:admin@example.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
<p>Name: <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="40"></p>
<p>E-mail address: <input name="E-mail" type="text" id="E-mail" size="40"></p>
<p>Comment:</p>
<p><textarea name="Comment" cols="55" rows="5"
id="Comment"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

it works really fine

Comment: What was wrong in my answer when I suggested using PHP and telling user solution won't always work?

Comment: original DVs were most likely due to the poor answer of just a simple link to another site. You have refined it now, but perhaps next time format it fully from the outset to avoid the DVs

Comment: Yeah but answer was correct - PHP is much reliable to send any data than using this method because it will not always work (what was described in the link). I added working solution but it seems php solution was chosen by the @user3604922

Comment: again... **right** *or* **wrong**, a simple link to another web site is generally frowned upon within the SO community. Elaboration here and **effort** spent in building the answer is usually best practice--as opposed to:     **"oh I use jquery to solve this cus it rocks and its easy...http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"**

Comment: i appreciate your effort to help me Marcin. I have chosen to use php to solve my problem since its too complicate if not impossible with html. Thanks again.